# Finding the limit of $\lim_{x\to 1} (x^2-\sqrt x)/(1-\sqrt x)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

How do I evaluate
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{(x^2-\sqrt x)}{(1-\sqrt x)}$$

Can someone explain the steps by steps solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use the substitution $$\sqrt x=t\Rightarrow x^2=t; x\to 1, t\to 1$$
$$\lim_ {x\to 1} \frac{x^2-\sqrt x}{1-\sqrt x}=\lim_ {t\to 1} \frac{t^4-t}{1-t}=\lim_ {t\to 1} \frac{t(t^3-1)}{1-t}=\lim_ {t\to 1} \frac{-t(1-t)(t^2+t+1)}{1-t}=\lim_ {t\to 1}-t(t^2+t+1)=$$
$$=-3$$

Answer (score 1):

By the L'Hôpital's rule
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2-\sqrt x}{1-\sqrt x}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{2x-\frac12x^{-1/2}}{-\frac12 x^{-1/2}}=\frac{2-\frac12}{-\frac12}=-3$$

Comment: Hope you're having a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Notice

$$ \frac{ x^2 - \sqrt{x}}{1 - \sqrt{x} } = \frac{ x^2 - \sqrt{x}}{1 - \sqrt{x} } \cdot \frac{1 + \sqrt{x}}{1+ \sqrt{x}} = \frac{x^2 + x^2 \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x} - x}{1-x} = \frac{x(x-1) + \sqrt{x}((x-1)(x+1)}{-(x-1)}= \frac{x + \sqrt{x}(x+1)}{-1} \to_{x \to 1} -3$$

Comment: $$\frac{x^2-\sqrt x}{1-\sqrt x}=\frac{x^2-\sqrt x}{1-\sqrt x}\cdot \frac{{1+\sqrt x}}{{1+\sqrt x}}=\frac{x^2+x^2\sqrt x- \sqrt x - x}{1-x}$$

Comment: Now is correct,